# How I can insert comments into my new SocialEngine Module

Tags: php, zend-framework, authorization, socialengine

Can you help with the following problem?

I would like to know how I can insert comments to my module.

I have followed the following steps:

my_new_root_model:

- Model:
  - DbTable:
    - my_new_models -> extends Engine_Db_Table
  - my_new_model -> extends Core_Model_Item_Abstract
    with functions comments and likes
- controllers:

  - my_new_model_controller -> extends Core_Controller_Action_Standard
                init:
    ```
    public function init()
        {
            // Get subject
            $mynewmodel = null;
            $mynewmodel_id = $this->_getParam('mynewmodel_id', $this->_getParam('id', null));

            if(!$mynewmodel_id)
                $mynewmodel = DEFAULT_VALUE;

            if( !$this->_helper->requireAuth()->setAuthParams('mynewrootmodel_mynewmodel', null, 'view')->isValid() ) return;

            $mynewmodel = Engine_Api::_()->getItem('mynewrootmodel_mynewmodel', $mynewmodel);
            if( $mynewmodel ) {
                Engine_Api::_()->core()->setSubject($mynewmodel);
            }

            // Require subject
            if( !$this->_helper->requireSubject()->isValid() ) {
                return;
            }
        }
    ```
- views:

  - scripts:

    - mynewmodel:

      - mynewmodel.tpl
        ```
         echo $this->action("list", "comment", "core", array("type"=>"mynewrootmodel_mynewmodel", "id"=>$this->mynewmodel->mynewmodel_id))
        ```

In DB:

engine4_authorization_permissions:

```
    __level_id  type                        name        value   params__

    __5         mynewrootmodel_mynewmodel   view        1       NULL__

    __5         mynewrootmodel_mynewmodel   comment     1       NULL__
```

engine4_authorization_allow:

```
    __resource_type             resource_id action  role        role_id     value   params__

    __mynewrootmodel_mynewmodel *id*        view    everyone    5           1       NULL__

    __mynewrootmodel_mynewmodel *id*        comment everyone    5           1       NULL__
```

I've got the information of modules as Album, Photo and Video

This code don't work.

What steps should I take to insert comments in my module?

Thanks

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: I need to know how I can insert comments to my module, and how I can control the authorization to make the information public, but to comment you have to login

Comment: That is a lot of questions in one. I think you'll find that people will be able to provide answers faster if you can keep it to one or a more specific question or problem.

Comment: ok!, first i only need insert comments into my new Module. What steps should I take to insert comments in my module?. I've tried several things, but does not work.

Comment: I changed the values ​​in the tables engine4_authorization_permissions engine4_authorization_allow and copy/paste the Album module (with minor tweaks) and now I see the comments in my module. :) . But I do not know exactly what it means each column. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Comment` widget under Core category in layout editor. You can put it on any page. To associate comments (and likes and tags) with a model you also need to have `comments()`, `likes()` and `tags()` methods implemented in the model class.